# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery-2.1.1.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, knockout.js

I am getting an error from the console in my website and it is originating from Jquery framework.

I think I may have $.each(data.results, function (index, items)){} wrong or I need to add more underneath it to specify what data I want displayed in my DOM. I am fairly new to knockout and Jquery.

I am using wcf service to output the data from a MySql db into Json for my application to read. I am using knockout to display and make sure the data updates as it changes.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var machineDataViewModel = {

        machineDataItems: ko.observableArray([]),

        loadMachineDataItems: function () {
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/JsonRestful/Service1.svc/GetMachineData", function (data) {
                machineDataViewModel.machineDataItems.removeAll();
                $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {
                    machineDataViewModel.machineDataItems.push(new machineDataModel(item));
                });
            });
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(machineDataViewModel);

    machineDataViewModel.loadMachineDataItems();

    //setInterval( loadMachineDataItems, 10000 );
});
```

And the elements in my view I am trying to map it to:

```
<div id="knockout" data-bind="foreach: machineDataItems">
    <p id="machineNum" data-bind="text: mach_no"></p>
    <div id="Completed" data-bind="text: VAR1"></div>
    <div id="Style" data-bind="text: VAR2"></div>
    <div id="PUPC" data-bind="text: VAR3"></div>
    <div id="RPM" data-bind="text: VAR4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `$.each` loop looks fine, so long as `data.results` is actually an array element. Can you confirm that is the case?

Comment: See my answer, but to sum it up, pretty sure your issue is that you need to call JSON.parse on the data you received back as it will be a string representation of JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is to do with the data coming in being a string json representation, maybe use JSON.parse on your incoming data to get it into JSON

I had the issue in the past too, I had a string come in from my Restfull API and Jquery complained about it whilest trying to foreach, so I would say you have the same issue that I had.

working fiddle using faked json with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/75otf0s8/4/

```
loadMachineDataItems: function () {
    (function (data) {
        machineDataViewModel.machineDataItems.removeAll();
        $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {
            machineDataViewModel.machineDataItems.push(new machineDataModel(item));
        });
     // passing in bogus data to the iffe as good json
    })({results: [{mach_no: '1', VAR1: '2', VAR2: '3', VAR3: '4', VAR4: '5'}, 
                  {mach_no: 'a1', VAR1: 'a2', VAR2: 'a3', VAR3: 'a4', VAR4: 'a5'},
                  {mach_no: 'b1', VAR1: 'b2', VAR2: 'b3', VAR3: 'b4', VAR4: 'b5'}]});
}
```

The fact that when I pass my moc'd data to where $.getJSON would have, it works makes me almost certain that getJSON is returning you string and not the Json $.each will iterate over.

Feel free to comment if you can't get JSON.prase to work.

edit:
Maybe read the following [Knockout Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html#updating-view-model-data-using-json). As you can see, they get the data in, convert it to proper JSON, then they can use!!! you would just replace data.results with the value returned by JSON.prase

Comment: Thank You Good Sir. I am trying it out now I'll let you know.

Comment: So the thing about my incoming data is that I am pretty sure it is already in JSON because that is what I made my Restful API to do. This is what my data looks like from my Wcf service [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bPAjxrm_wlb29fRG40N0ZaX2s/view?usp=sharing) . I really appreciate your help

Comment: I guess what I got my Restful API is just a message? I see that you made a results array in the jsfiddle sample. So I need to find a way to parse my data into a results array or do something like this? [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu68y6hg/) And should I use the $.each or does this for loop work?

Comment: Yea I don't know why it still won't work. The code all makes sense to me but nothing is outputting in my view..